# Плавное замена блоков при hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую помогите доработать jquery. при Hover на блок, Первый блок должен исчезать с стилем SlideUp, а за ним должен наполнить второй блок с таким же стилем SlideUp. а при удалении стрелка мыши обратный стиль с SLideDown
В мои случаях, они исчезали быстро, те курсор стоить в стиле hover а в то обратный скрипт применяется. Они должны стоять, пока курсор стоит. [Код на *JSFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/gyavises/yfce5sqc/).

HTML:

```
<div id="objects">
<div class="advantage">
   <p class="h2">Этот блок должен исчезать с стилем slideUp</p>
 </div>
<div class="advantage-hover">
   <p class="h2">Этот блок должен появляться после исчезнование первого блока с стилем slideUp</p>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- То есть второй блок advantage-hover заменять плавно первого блока -->
```

CSS:

```
.advantage {
 width:130px;
 height:130px;
 background:red;
}
.advantage-hover {
  display:none;
  width:130px;
  height:130px;
  background:blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$().hover(
  function() {
    $(.advantage).slideUp();
    $(.advantage-hover).slideUp();
  },
  function() {
    $(.advantage).slideDown();
    $(.advantage-hover).slideDown();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение вашей задачи: http://jsfiddle.net/shugich/nbLhfp67/1/

```js
$('.advantage').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).slideUp()
  $('.advantage-hover').slideDown();
});
$('.advantage-hover').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).slideUp()
  $('.advantage').slideDown();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.advantage {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background: red;
}
.advantage-hover {
  background: blue;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="objects">
  <div class="advantage">
    <p class="h2">Этот блок должен исчезать с стилем slideUp</p>
  </div>
  <div class="advantage-hover">
    <p class="h2">Этот блок должен появляться после исчезнование первого блока с стилем slideUp</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- То есть второй блок advantage-hover заменять плавно первого блока -->
```